# Ejected bodies, dynamical friction and dark energy?

Tags: cosmology, black-holes, astrophysics, space-expansion, dark-energy

I have a question after reading a couple of papers (https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.06220 and https://www.arxiv-vanity.com/papers/1102.0007/).

Here, the authors seem to indicate that when bodies like stars or black holes are ejected from their host galaxies or clusters of galaxies, dark energy "helps" them to escape into infinity.

I asked the authors one question:

They say that there is an acceleration component due to Dark Energy. Although Dark Energy has a very small contribution to the velocity of the escaping bodies (stars, black holes...), they seem to indicate that Dark Energy then adds a little bit of velocity to these escaping black holes as they travel out of their galaxy or galaxy cluster as well as decreasing the escape velocity limit due to the "anti-gravity" effect of Dark Energy. They basically told me that both things indeed were happening.

Then I wondered...

1. Once they have escaped from the galaxy or their local galaxy cluster, could they crash with other bodies in intergalactic space? Or perhaps be absorbed by other galaxies? Or at these distances the expansion of the universe is so overwhelming that they get isolated?
2. As these stars and black holes travel their way out (with a little bit of help from Dark Energy) they suffer dynamical friction from the other components in their host systems (especially for massive objects like supermassive black holes). Does this cause some form of heat?

PS: I've noticed there is a downvote. I would appreciate if someone could point out any mistakes that the question may have